# updating tagged words in a text

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a tagged text. The tagged text contains some incorrect tagged words. So I made a based-rules tagger for the words which the original tagger can not tag. And I want to replace in the tagged text only the wrong tagged words with correct one.
the format of the tagged text is

```
il/P ragazzo/V vuole/V andare/V a/P scuola/V`
```

the format of the correct tags is:

```
[(u'porta', 'NN'), (u'scuola', 'NN'), (u'ragazzo', 'NN')]
```

And the output will be `

```
il/P ragazzo/NN vuole/V andare/V a/P scuola/NN`
```

I tried to create two dictionaries: one for the tagged text and one for the correct tags and then replace the values once the keys are the same, but the dictionary does not respect the original order of the text, but gives me the output in disorder. Can someone know how to replace the incorrect tagged words in the original text. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `nltk.str2tuple` module to convert your tagged string to tuples , then go through first list and if you have a same element in first element of `correct_tag_list` then chose that item from `correct_tag_list` (`k`) else choose that element from first list itself (`i,j`) :

```
>>> from nltk.tag.util import str2tuple
>>> s1=[(unicode(i),j) for i,j in [str2tuple(i) for i in s.split()]]
>>> l_first=[i[0] for i in l]
>>> [tuple(k for k in l if i==k[0])[0] if i in l_first else (i,j) for i,j in s1]
    [(u'il', 'P'), (u'ragazzo', 'NN'), (u'vuole', 'V'), (u'andare', 'V'), (u'a', 'P'), (u'scuola', 'NN')]
```

Demo :

```
>>> s="il/P ragazzo/V vuole/V andare/V a/P scuola/V"
>>> l=[(u'porta', 'NN'), (u'scuola', 'NN'), (u'ragazzo', 'NN')]
>>> from nltk.tag.util import str2tuple
>>> [str2tuple(i) for i in s.split()]
[('il', 'P'), ('ragazzo', 'V'), ('vuole', 'V'), ('andare', 'V'), ('a', 'P'), ('scuola', 'V')]
>>> s1=[(unicode(i),j) for i,j in s1]
>>> s1
[(u'il', 'P'), (u'ragazzo', 'V'), (u'vuole', 'V'), (u'andare', 'V'), (u'a', 'P'), (u'scuola', 'V')]
>>> l_first=[i[0] for i in l]
>>> l_first
[u'porta', u'scuola', u'ragazzo']
>>> [tuple(k for k in l if i==k[0])[0] if i in l_first else (i,j) for i,j in s1]
[(u'il', 'P'), (u'ragazzo', 'NN'), (u'vuole', 'V'), (u'andare', 'V'), (u'a', 'P'), (u'scuola', 'NN')]
```

If you don't want to sue `nltk.str2tuple` use convert string to tupple with following code just using `split()`

```
>>> [tuple(i.split('/')) for i in s.split()]
[('il', 'P'), ('ragazzo', 'V'), ('vuole', 'V'), ('andare', 'V'), ('a', 'P'), ('scuola', 'V')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use dictionary for tags and then convert input to output in a loop, preserving order:

```
input = 'hil/P ragazzo/V vuole/V andare/V a/P scuola/V'
rules = [(u'porta', 'NN'), (u'scuola', 'NN'), (u'ragazzo', 'NN')]

rules_dict = {rule[0]: rule[1] for rule in rules}

parts = []
for token in input.split():
    word, type = token.split('/')
    if word in rules_dict:
        parts.append(word + '/' + rules_dict[word])
    else:
        parts.append(token)

output = ' '.join(parts)
print(output)
```